# RHEL 7 Server Network not working after Install Python3.6 from Source

Tags: linux, ssl, redhat, python, make

I have a RHEL server which by default was running Python2.7 and Python3.4

I needed to use Python3.6 so I downloaded it and built it from source. However, now I seemed to have broken my network connectivity. I can still ssh into the box but none of my HTTPS calls are working which leads me to believe its related to an SSL lib.

After doing research I see that I should have done `make altinstall` instead of `make install`

Does anyone know how to reverse this, or where I may look for issues??

Comment: Sometimes, the `make install ` comand will create a list of the installed files. This list allow the execution of `make uninstall`, that will remove the installed files. Maybe you'll need to reinstall your distro's python packages, as some files could be overwriten.

Comment: You can also try to bring your interfaces up manuallly, using `ip address` or `ifconfig` for setting the IP and `ip route` or `route` for setting the deafult gateway.

Comment: The network is ok - I can ssh into the box. I just can't make outgoing https connections. I am thinking the SSL lib is broken

Comment: What are you trying to do (the comand ...)? Are you able to do a `nc google.com 443`?

Comment: I am behind a restricted firewall. I can only hit certain sites. I have tried python requests, curl, wget to approved sites. All of which worked before i did this

Comment: @JucaPirama I have tried looking for the uninstall file but I do not think I have one

Comment: It isn't a file. It is a `make` target. Go to the python source dir where you executed the `make install` and try to run `make uninstall`.

Comment: @JucaPirama I have tried that. No such luck :(

Comment: Someone said (in other post, sorry can't find the source now) to execute `make -n install`. This will simultate the install process, and show a list of files that would be copied and their destination. Maybe this can be a starting point.

Comment: Also, you could try to identify the original installed python packages (something like `rpm -qa | grep python > /tmp/python.txt`) and reinstall them with `yum reinstall ` (something like `cat /tmp/python.txt | xargs yum -y reinstall`). This (I hope) should fix your python install and libs.

Comment: @JucaPirama  I tried the `make -n` command but it spits out way too much that is over my head. The other command looked promising but Yum is failing - Do you know of a way I can run `make` on python3.4 again? this is one of the versions the system started with and where I suspect the issue is stemming from

Comment: Check my previous comment about yum reinstall, for trying to reinstall your packages.

Comment: @JucaPirama  I tried the `yum reinstall` command but it error'd out.

Comment: I'm out of ideas here, sry. But the last thing comming to my mind is: as the only broken connectivity is related to python packages, you could try install python3.6 inside a virtual environment. It won't solve your main problem (system's python broken), but allows for running programs in a python3 environment isolated from the system. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear but the system's connectivity is broken. I cannot `wget` or `curl`  - Anyway, thank for the help I do appreciate it

Comment: EPEL is now on Python 3.6. You probably do not need to install from source.

Answer (score 2):

Try Red Hat Software Collections. [The package is rh-python-36.](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python36/) In the rhscl repo and a [python3 tutorial on the developer blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/), so someone at Red Hat uses it.

Edit: as mentioned in the comments, python36 from EPEL gives you exactly that. So you have at least two choices specifically packaged for RHEL 7.

Installing from source is educational, but time consuming to sort out the dependencies. And reproducible builds are not always easy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue, but I am still not sure of the root cause. My best guess is that I installed 3.6 incorrectly (did not use `altinstall`) and I overwrote some critical python2 system links.

To resolve I fully removed Python3.6, fully removed Python3.4, and then removed and reinstalled 2.7. Once 2.7 was re-installed I had my connectivity back.